# Looping an fgets statement only using functions in stdio.h

Tags: c

Let us consider the following code snippet :

```
int main()
{
    printf("jkjkkjkj \n");

    int p, n;
    FILE *fp, *gp;
    /*getchar();*/

    printf("jkjkkjkj2 \n");
    /*getchar();*/

    fp = fopen("abc.txt","w");
    printf("kjkj \n)");
    fputs("chjkjkbu rey",fp);
    fputs("bklklbu1234rey ",fp);

    /*fputs("chuhibu rey ",fp);*/
    printf("kjkj2 \n)");

    n = fclose(fp);
    printf("kjkj3 \n)");
    fp = fopen ("abc.txt","r");
    printf("kjkj4 \n)");

    char j[20];
    printf("kjkj5 \n)");
    n = *(fgets(j,12,fp));

    printf ("moron \n");
    printf("... %s",j);
    printf("\n marun");

    while (n = *(fgets(j,10,fp)))
    {
        printf("kjkj5.5 \n)");
        /*fgets(j, 10, fp);*/

        printf("it's... %s \n", j);
        printf("kjkj6 \n)");
        /*j = n;*/
        printf("kjkj7 \n)");
        printf( "the chareacter here is %c \n", n);
        printf("kjkj8 \n)");
   }

   n = fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Now I want to read the file line by line but I will get segmentation fault in the line where the file ends.
(Please ignore compilation errors if any for the

I wanted to know if I can modify the condition in the while loop without adding 
any function from some different library

Comment: Its OK to read in less than the buffer size with 10 or 12, but with `char j[20];` I'd expect  `fgets(j,sizeof j ,fp);` to allow reading up to 19 characters.

Answer (score 4):

When `fgets` hits the end of a file and no characters have been read, it will return `NULL`, and in error cases too. As you are dereferencing returned value of `fgets`, you will get an undefined behavior when `fgets` returns `NULL`, which is the cause of the crash in your program. What you have to do, is to check only if returned value of `fgets` is different from `NULL`:

```
while (fgets(j, 10, fp) != NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should loop while `fgets` doesn't return a null pointer. E.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`.

If you want to get the first character of `j` (which is what `*fgets(...)` will give you) then get it inside the loop:

```
n = j[0];  // Equal to n = *j
```